# operation on array of object using async.forEach

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I am new to node.js and I have written code using async.forEach().Something is wrong I am not getting my mistake.

```
async.forEach(payload.bookings,fun,function(err,res){
        var data ;
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        if(res) {

            data = res;
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    function fun(booking,cb){

        var dataToSave = {};

        //service choosen by customer
        var service_id = booking.serviceId;

        dataToSave.serviceId = service_id;

        var query = {
            services : {$elemMatch : { serviceId : service_id } }
        };

        var projection = {
            cellPhoneNumber :1,
            countryCode:1,
            services :1
        };

        var options = {};

        Service.serviceProvider.getServiceProviders(query,projection,options,function(err,data){

            if(err)
                cb(err);
            else{

                if(data && data.length>0){

                    //getting list of SP which gives the service name given by customer
                    dataToSave.serviceProviderList = [];

                    for(var sp=0;sp<data.length;sp++){

                        var serviceProvider = {};

                        serviceProvider.id = data[sp]._id;

                        //searching in services array of one particular service id
                        for(var j=0;j<data[sp].services.length;j++){

                            if(data[sp].services[j].serviceId==service_id)
                            {
                                serviceProvider.serviceRate = data[sp].services[j].rate;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        dataToSave.serviceProviderList.push(serviceProvider);
                    }
                    cb(dataToSave);
                }
                else{
                    cb();
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Output:

```
{ serviceId: '578e0da7c8c4cfc807040852',
  serviceProviderList: 
   [ { id: 578e18f6ed564791083c75ad, serviceRate: 200 },
     { id: 578e1996ed564791083c75b4, serviceRate: 200 } ] }
```

Expected output :

```
{ serviceId: '578e0da7c8c4cfc807040852',
  serviceProviderList: 
   [ { id: 578e18f6ed564791083c75ad, serviceRate: 200 },
     { id: 578e1996ed564791083c75b4, serviceRate: 200 } ] }
{ serviceId: '578dca50e93da81f0423f6b6',
  serviceProviderList: [ { id: 578e18f6ed564791083c75ad, serviceRate: 100 } ] }
```

I have seen on swagger documentation.When I click on **Try It Out** it keeps on running.only it shows the object which I have printed using console.log()

Comment: Which version of async are u using?

Comment: @Iceman  "async": "^2.0.0-rc.6"

Comment: Couldn't find `.forEach()` in the docs, though you write it exactly with `.each()` syntax.

Comment: payload.bookings is array or object

Comment: @FooVirus payload.bookings is an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably lies in the `cb(dataToSave);` line. The pattern for the callbacks is `cb(err, results);`. By executing `cb(dataToSave);` the async.js believes you ran into an error.

Try changing it to `cb(null, dataToSave);`

```
                    (...)
                    }
                    dataToSave.serviceProviderList.push(serviceProvider);
                }
                cb(null, dataToSave);
            }
            (...)
```